# Formatter parameter is being passed null after setting a new model

Tags: sapui5

In my XML for a List object I have made use of a formatter:

```js
{path: 'Erdat', formatter: '.formatter.dateFormatter'}
```

This works as expected and I can see the bound value for `Erdat` passed into `dateFormatter` and then formatted appropriately. However, on my app I have an option to re-call the back-end gateway service, which will re-bind the newly fetched data to the List (`listLogs`):

```js
oActLogs.read("/ActivityLogsSet", {
  success: function (oData, oResponse){
    oActivityLogsModel.setData(oData);
    listLogs.setModel(oActivityLogsModel);
    oGlobalBusyDialog.close();
  },
  // ...
});
```

This works and I can see the new data being fetched from the service. However, when I set this new model to `listLogs` the formatter is hit but this time it is being passed `null`, and then crashes when the formatter tries to do anything with this value.

I have debugged and seen that on this second call the data fetched is not null, so why is null being passed to the formatter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess I would say that any change in the binding will trigger the formatter. That might also be an 'unbind' happening before you bind the new model. Or you bind the new model before the data is actually loaded.

Why not just do something like this in your formatter:

```js
dateFormatter: function(oValue) {
  if (!oValue) {
    return "";
  }
  // do the real stuff
}
```

It is good practice to make your formatter return something useful (at least an empty string) even if it's inputs are crappy which can easily happen for different reasons (model not yet exists, data not yet loaded, ...). This will prevent your UI from showing ugly stuff like 'undefined'.

Btw: did you consider using [Types](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/dfe04650afc046e0802abb1a1a90d2d9) for date formatting?

BR
Chris

Comment: Thanks Chris, you were correct, I watched it hit the formatter twice, once with null and then again with the new value. I'll have a look into the Types option as well